# Make WAMP being accessible through localhost instead of localhost:8080 (or specific port)

Tags: apache, port, wamp

I've installeed wamp and it runs fine, all except if I want to access it I *have* to type in localhost:8080 (the 8080 is the port it listens to).

Can I make it so that it just works with localhost without requiring the port number to be entered and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else has already grabbed port 80, that is why it wont work.

Run 
wampmanager->Apache->Service->Test port 80

This will launch a command window and tell you what is using port 80.

Whatever it is will need to be re-configured to use another port or for example if its IIS and you dont use IIS it should be un-installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this site for a bit more information: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,13744.

You're going to want to edit your http.conf file, searching for 8080, and replacing it with 80, where applicable. I know that is generic, but that is the best I can do without actually seeing your http.conf file.

Comment: I did change it with 80 and it won't work at all, when I try to go to localhost:80 it redirects to localhost and gives me a 404, when i try to go to localhost it gives me a 404 too.

I updated 'servername' in http conf to be localhost without the :80 but still no dicel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the port Apache is listenning to.

Access apache/conf/httpd.conf under your WAMP directory.

In this file, there will be a "Listen 8080", change it to whatever port you want to.

You must restart Apache after this. It can be achieved using Services in Windows.

If the service does not restart (and you havent messed up your config file), it is because the port you chose is already in use and you wont be able to use it.

If you want to use multiple ports for each project, consider reading about Apache Virtual Hosting.

Hope I helped